# Python Bottle Image part 2

Tags: python, image, static, bottle

im unsure, if im not understanding the bottle tutorial correctly but this code:

```
from bottle import static_file

@route('/images/<filename:re:.*\.png>')
def send_image(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/image/files', mimetype='image/png')
```

is supposed to look through the folder for that image name without having to add .png to the name, right?

so if i have a file named python.png

i would type into the browser .../python, and this should get me the image, right?

because im not getting the image but i do get it when i add .png to it

Comment: I think the point is that you can _only_ get .png files

Comment: oh, okay. thanks. is there a way in the bottle framework to look for an image without specifying .png? or would i have to code it in?

Answer (score 3):

Well, answering the question you asked in the comment...

```
@route('/images/:filename')
def send_image(filename):
    return static_file(filename + '.png', root='/path/to/image/files', mimetype='image/png')
```

Comment: If you want to work with subfolders, use :filename#.*# or <filename:path> on your route.